# Angular4 blank screen after importing component

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster

I am facing the following problem: 
I have generated a JHipster Application and now need to import a component inside another component like shown in this tutorial:

https://coursetro.com/courses/12/Learn-Angular-4-from-Scratch/lessons/2

I have a TeamMember.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks, JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { Team } from './team.model';
import { TeamService } from './team.service';
import { ITEMS_PER_PAGE, Principal, ResponseWrapper } from '../../shared';

@Component({
selector: 'jhi-team',
templateUrl: './team.component.html'
})
export class TeamComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
teams: Team[];
currentAccount: any;
eventSubscriber: Subscription;

constructor(
    private teamService: TeamService,
    private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
    private eventManager: JhiEventManager,
    private principal: Principal
) {
}

loadAll() {
    this.teamService.query().subscribe(
        (res: ResponseWrapper) => {
            this.teams = res.json;
        },
        (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json)
    );
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAll();
    this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
        this.currentAccount = account;
    });
    this.registerChangeInTeams();
    this.teamService.query();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
}

trackId(index: number, item: Team) {
    return item.id;
}
registerChangeInTeams() {
    this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('teamListModification', (response) => this.loadAll());
}

private onError(error) {
    this.jhiAlertService.error(error.message, null, null);
}
}
```

and a Team.component, where I want to import the teammembers.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { EntrestratsSharedModule } from '../../shared';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {DataListModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {TeamMemberComponent} from '../team-member/team-member.component';

import {
TeamService,
TeamPopupService,
TeamComponent,
TeamDetailComponent,
TeamDialogComponent,
TeamPopupComponent,
TeamDeletePopupComponent,
TeamDeleteDialogComponent,
teamRoute,
teamPopupRoute,
} from './';

const ENTITY_STATES = [
...teamRoute,
...teamPopupRoute,
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    EntrestratsSharedModule,
    ButtonModule,
    DataListModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ENTITY_STATES, { useHash: true }),
],
declarations: [
    TeamComponent,
    TeamMemberComponent,
    TeamDetailComponent,
    TeamDialogComponent,
    TeamDeleteDialogComponent,
    TeamPopupComponent,
    TeamDeletePopupComponent,
],
entryComponents: [
    TeamComponent,
    TeamDialogComponent,
    TeamPopupComponent,
    TeamDeleteDialogComponent,
    TeamDeletePopupComponent,
],
providers: [
    TeamService,
    TeamPopupService,
],
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class EntrestratsTeamModule {}
```

My Problem is the following:

If I do this as described in the tutorial and as shown in my code snippets, I only get a blank page for this app. I don't get an error, just a white page for the whole app.

Has anyone experienced this and some ideas for me? I sit on this the whole day now and don't have an idea what I could do with this.

Thank you in advance for all suggestions!

Karsten

EDIT:

Maybe it helps if i share my package.json:

```html
{
"name": "entrestrats",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "Description for entrestrats",
"private": true,
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"cacheDirectories": [
"node_modules"
],
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.34",
"@angular/animations": "4.3.2",
"@angular/common": "4.3.2",
"@angular/compiler": "4.3.2",
"@angular/core": "4.3.2",
"@angular/forms": "4.3.2",
"@angular/http": "4.3.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.2",
"@angular/router": "4.3.2",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
"core-js": "2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"ng-jhipster": "0.2.12",
"ng2-webstorage": "1.8.0",
"ngx-cookie": "1.0.0",
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
"popper.js": "1.11.0",
"primeng": "^4.3.0",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
"rxjs": "5.4.2",
"swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
"tether": "1.4.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.16"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.4.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.2",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
"@types/node": "8.0.18",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.2",
"browser-sync": "2.18.13",
"browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.2.0",
"codelyzer": "3.1.2",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"exports-loader": "0.6.4",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"generator-jhipster": "4.10.2",
"html-loader": "0.5.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
"karma": "1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
"karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
"karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
"merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.11",
"ngc-webpack": "3.2.2",
"node-sass": "4.5.3",
"postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
"proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
"puppeteer": "0.10.2",
"rimraf": "2.6.1",
"sass-loader": "6.0.6",
"sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
"string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.1.3",
"style-loader": "0.18.2",
"to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
"tslint": "5.5.0",
"tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
"typescript": "2.5.2",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.0.0-beta.2",
"web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
"webpack": "3.6.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
"webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
"webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
"write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.1.0",
"xml2js": "0.4.17"
},
"engines": {
"node": ">=6.9.0"
},
"scripts": {
"lint": "tslint --type-check --project './tsconfig.json' -e 'node_modules/**'",
"lint:fix": "yarn run lint -- --fix",
"ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
"cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
"clean-www": "rimraf target//www/app/{src,target/}",
"start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
"serve": "yarn run start",
"build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
"test": "karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js",
"test:watch": "yarn test -- --watch",
"webpack:dev": "yarn run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base",
"webpack:build:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
"webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:main",
"webpack:prod:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile",
"webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www",
"webpack:test": "yarn run test",
"webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
"webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
}
```

Comment: usually a blank page means you have a compilation error. What do you see in the terminal window where you ran `ng serve`?

Comment: Tahnk you, @inorganik for your comment.
I can't use ng serve as I found out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865412/ng-serve-fails-webpack-fails-to-compile-error-in-src-main-webapp-manifest

When I run it, I don't get any error, just a warning about trailing whitespace. Is this severe?

Comment: I would recommend you to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44313593/7682577)

Answer (score 0):

It can sound crazy but try importing the:
**templateUrl: './team.component.html'**
without the './'
**templateUrl: 'team.component.html'**
and also add the 
**moduleId: module.id** above the selector.

Comment: Hello @facundo, 

this unfortunately did not help, thank you. Do you have another idea?